# Skip multiple before filters in a Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have filters in a controller like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_filter :set_params
  before_filter :set_default_response_format
  before_filter :require_key

end
```

In one action I need to skip two of the three filters, so I tried this:

```
skip_before_filter [:require_key, :set_params], only: [:special_action]
```

That does not work. It doesn't skip anything. Then I tried this, which also doesn't work:

```
skip_before_filter :require_key, only: [:special_action]
skip_before_filter :set_params, only: [:special_action]
```

So my question is: how to skip multiple before filters in a Rails controller?

Comment: Have you tried `skip_filter`? Seems this function is from [Rails < 3.0 and is deprecated](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods/skip_before_filter)

Comment: Since you're on Rails 4, have you tried using `before_action` and `skip_before_action` yet? The "filter" term is deprecated.

Comment: Also, you wouldn't use an array to list multiple actions to skip. Just list them like `skip_before_action :require_key, :set_params, only: :special_action`

Comment: Yes, I've tried `skip_filter`, `before_action` and `skip_before_action`, and just listing the actions instead of using an array. It's amazing...

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

before_action :first_action, :second_action, :third_action, :fourth_action, :fifth_action, :sixth_action, :seventh_action, only: [:index, :show, :create]